# C++ Making a code writer

Tags: c++, io, generator, game-engine, writer

Firstly my experience with c++ is limited! I am working on a level editor for a game engine and I was wondering if I could have some sort of system were things were done in the level editor and the program would write c++ code for the user. Nothing complicated now, just a few lines added to a function here and there.

I am clueless about were to start so I was hoping someone could point me to a book or some sort of a guidance in making something to read and write c++ code for you. Has this ever been done before is the no need for it?

Or is there workarounds?

David

Comment: I'm not sure this is a a good application for intro C++.

Comment: You are better off having the level editor spit out a config file to be passed to the game engine that describes the level. Changing the code would require it to be compiled again and is more work to maintain.

Comment: It's not clear what you have in mind. As mentioned, a level editor usually produces data not code, so I think most of us are unsure what problem you want to solve. On today's embedded and mobile platforms using code as 'data' isn't necessarily so bad since an app bundle has to be rebuilt even when data changes, but it all depends on what you want to do. Steve Rabin of Nintendo of America has a great series of articles in the AI Game Programming Wisdom books on using C macros for a state machine scripting language that is superior to all other FSM libraries I've seen, but that is an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use a language such as [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) or [Python](http://www.python.org/) as a scripting language for a game engine. It makes no sense to produce more C++ for the ingame events and scripting (as it needs to be compiled and the language is more demanding to write than other languages).

Comment: Thanks, thinking over it again it does sound like a stupid idea, I think a config file would be the best plan